# MVC Display data based on users login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this table where displaying the list of userID+SubjectID, now i want is,if the user who Logged in can only see the list of Subject that belongs to the current user,is it possible? then should i need to use asp.net identity? currently i am using empty template with custom login Authentication + Roles only, any idea on what is the best way to handle this type of scenario? all i want is my tables will show data based on the current user logged in.

**Example:** If User1 logged in then User1 will only see subjects belong to user1..

**Note:**
i was searching for tutorials on showing data based on the current user logged in, but i couldn't find,any one has better idea? or link can share with me? i don't know the better word for my scenario i just call it "show data based on current user",i appreciate if anyone can solve this..thanks in advance..

**Table Controller:**

```
[CostumAuthorize(Roles = "Admin,Teacher")]
    public ActionResult Subject_List(int id)
    {
        var test = db.SubjectTeachers.Where(x => x.Users.Any(n => n.UserID == id)).ToList();
        var subjectTeachers = db.SubjectTeachers.Include(s => s.Levels).Include(s => s.Subjects).Include(s => s.Users).Where(u => u.LevelID == id);
        return View(subjectTeachers.ToList());


    }
```

**Account controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Login l, string ReturnUrl = "")
    {



        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(l);
        }
        using (MyContext dc = new MyContext())
        {
            var user = dc.Users.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(l.Username) && a.Password.Equals(l.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, l.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                }


                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }

        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login.");
        return View(l);
}


    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the logged-in userid then simply use that to get Corresponding Subjects list.........

```
int userid = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
[CostumAuthorize(Roles = "Admin,Teacher")]
public ActionResult Subject_List()
{
   var test = db.SubjectTeachers.Where(x => x.Users.Any(n => n.UserID == userid )).ToList();
   return View(test.ToList());
}
```

Comment: How to get? any Idea

Comment: that depends on authentication which you implemented in your project...here you mentioned(in question) as custom login Authentication